# Can an SVG element be allowed to overflow its mask?

Tags: svg

Currently working on a project that uses a slider to compare two different images overlaid with SVG's. SVG's on the right side of the slider have a mask applied to them while the SVG's on the left should remain unchanged.

My problem is that when using a mask to apply these styles the mask clips any of the element that it doesn't cover.

Reproduction CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNEOPy

Super minimal repro:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <pattern
      id="pattern"
      width="10"
      height="10"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#999"></circle>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="masker">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="25%" fill="url(#pattern)"></rect>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" mask="url(#masker)"></circle>
</svg>
```

What I would like to do is apply the mask to the portion of the element that the mask covers and allow the rest of the element to remain visible/unchanged.

This CodePen demonstrates the behavior I am looking for, but requires duplicating each of the SVG's (which is unfortunately not technically feasible in my case): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vMzwbP

Is there a way to achieve this behavior with masking? Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  You are always going to have to have two instances of the circle. One with the mask applied, and one with no mask (or the inverse mask).